# Différence entre en supposant que et si tant est que

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre "en supposant que" et "si tant est que". Je suis en train d'apprendre les conjonctions de condition mais je ne sais pas quand je dois utiliser en supposant que et quand si tant est que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« En supposant que *suivi du* subj » sert à formuler une supposition. Il n'y a aucune espèce de jugement attaché à la supposition.

> En supposant qu'il lise cela avant demain, il trouvera.

« Si tant est que *suivi du* subj ; cette locution  sert à formuler une supposition mais en même temps à émettre un doute concernant la plausibilité de cette supposition.

> Si tant est qu'il lise cela avant demain, il trouvera.

*Si c'est vrai qu'il aura lu cela avant demain, il trouvera.* _ *S'il est possible qu'il ait lu cela avant demain, il trouvera.*